# CloudPageBlob StartCopyAsync Fails with status 404

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am running into an issue where I am trying to copy a CloudPageBlob to a storage account that is in a different Azure Subscription.  For some reason, when I make the call to copy, I keep on getting a 404 error:

```
CloudBlobContainer destContainer;
CloudBlob sourceBlob;
string destBlobName;

var sourcePageBlob = sourceBlob as CloudPageBlob;
if (sourcePageBlob != null)
{
    var destBlob = destContainer.GetPageBlobReference(destBlobName);
    await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourcePageBlob, AccessCondition.GenerateIfExistsCondition(), AccessCondition.GenerateEmptyCondition(), new BlobRequestOptions(), new OperationContext());
    return destBlob;
}
```

The call returns `{"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}`
However if I call `sourcePageBlob.Exists()` it returns `true`.

Comment: Does you destContainer exist? 404 error may be due to that. Besides, since you specify AccessCondition.GenerateIfExistsCondition(), I think destBlob needs to exist as well. Why not remove this access condition?

Comment: Can you please check the source container ACL? Is it `Private`?

Comment: Yes, the source container is private.  Should that matter?  I have an access key to it and am able to perform operations on the source container.

Answer (score 7):

Having a private source container was the issue.  You need to get a Shared Access URI that will allow the destination storage account to access the source one.  This blog post explains it: https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/copy-blobs-with-startcopyfromblob-and-track-its-progression-using-copystate/

```
CloudBlobContainer destContainer;
CloudBlob sourceBlob;
string destBlobName;

var sharedAccessUri = GetShareAccessUri(sourceBlob);
var sourcePageBlob = sourceBlob as CloudPageBlob;
if (sourcePageBlob != null)
{
    var destBlob = destContainer.GetPageBlobReference(destBlobName);
    await destBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(sharedAccessUri));
    return destBlob;
}

private string GetShareAccessUri(CloudBlob sourceBlob)
{
  int validMins = 300;
  var policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
  {
    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessStartTime = null,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(validMins)
  };

  var sas = sourceBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
  return sourceBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas;
}
```